# Retrieve JSON values from Javascript array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to using JSON and Javascript, but I am trying to sort various values of the JSON file provided by Reddit. In the console, I do see the array and the JSON values from the console.log(posts) print. However, the console.log(posts.length) statement returns 0 and nothing is displayed to the screen, which I suspect is due to how I am storing and/or retrieving the JSON values in the array.

```js
var minVotes = 5;
var subreddit = "askreddit";
var posts = [];
//Retrieve JSON from Reddit using JQuery
$.getJSON("https://www.reddit.com/r/" + subreddit + "/rising.json?limit=50", function foo(result) {
  $.each(result.data.children.slice(0, 50), function(i, post) {

    if (post.data.ups > minVotes) {
      //Push JSON data to array to be sorted later
      posts.push(post.data);
    }
  })
})

//Sort the array
posts.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseInt(a.data.ups - a.data.num_comments) - parseInt(b.data.ups - b.data.num_comments);
});

console.log(posts);
console.log(posts.length); //returns 0 ???

//Display the content, which doesn't work
for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
  $("#reddit-content").append('<br>' + "Title: " + posts[i].title);
  $("#reddit-content").append('<br>' + "Url: " + posts[i].url);
  $("#reddit-content").append('<br>' + "Upvotes: " + posts[i].ups);
  $("#reddit-content").append('<br>' + "Comments: " + posts[i].num_comments);
  $("#reddit-content").append('<hr>');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reddit-content"></div>
```

Comment: Can you abstract away all the Redditness? And the HTTP? Hardcode some input into your example. Present a self-contained example.

Comment: How does `posts` look when logged?

Comment: [Console output](http://i.imgur.com/wTCBHU9.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the async nature of `$.getJSON`. If you sort the array inside the response handler it works fine.

You also had another issue in your sort with accessing the property values. I don't believe you need to `parseInt` either as `JSON.parse` will return those values as numbers already.

```js
var minVotes = 5;
var subreddit = "askreddit";
//Retrieve JSON from Reddit using JQuery
$.getJSON("https://www.reddit.com/r/" + subreddit + "/rising.json?limit=50", function foo(result) {
  var posts = [];

  $.each(result.data.children.slice(0, 50), function(i, post) {
    if (post.data.ups > minVotes) {
      //Push JSON data to array to be sorted later
      posts.push(post.data);
    }
  });

  //Sort the array
  posts.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.ups - a.num_comments) - parseInt(b.ups - b.num_comments);
  });

  console.log(posts);
  console.log(posts.length);

  //Display the content, which doesn't work
  for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    $("#reddit-content").append('<br>' + "Title: " + posts[i].title);
    $("#reddit-content").append('<br>' + "Url: " + posts[i].url);
    $("#reddit-content").append('<br>' + "Upvotes: " + posts[i].ups);
    $("#reddit-content").append('<br>' + "Comments: " + posts[i].num_comments);
    $("#reddit-content").append('<hr>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reddit-content"></div>
```